# Is there a reason my formula changed the equation of a table within itself?

Tags: excel

I think I have discovered a bug, or someone is messing with my Excel. Either way, I need help. All of my spreadsheets have equations that reference tables. However, the references to those tables within the formulas have all gone to shit. The equations do not work anymore and all result in a #N/A.

To provide some background, the formulas look at a row within a table and take the most recently inputed value. Each week, we record values. A recorded value is placed as a number without any asterisk. However, if we didn't record a value that week, the previous week's value is put into place of that week's section and an asterisk is added to note that it isn't an actually recorded value. That's the whole purpose of the substitute part (which I do not think is the issue). Also, the A6 is just a value I've been in the spreadsheet as the row number of the table for it to search.

Also, within the HLOOKUP, the G3 is the date and pretty much the HLOOKUP looks up the current date's value recorded and parses out the asterisk.

This is what the equation looks like now:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(HLOOKUP(G3,Table25891314151834077[#All],A6,FALSE),"*","")
```

This is what the equation should look like:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(HLOOKUP(G3,Table2[#All],A6,FALSE),"*","")
```

I have no idea how this happened, but I am going through my versions that I saved as I built my spreadsheets, and all the version have this same issue. When I click on the "table2589.......[#All], it highlights the correct table area. Is this some setting that I fucked up? Or did they change something with tables? Anything helps!

Comment: I've not seen that issue reported anywhere, so it is likely something in your environment that caused the problem.

Comment: I was afraid so but I have no idea what could cause something like that.

Comment: Start by setting up a simple table on a new worksheet and see if it changes names.  If it does not, add steps, one at a time, as you do in your misbehaving data, until the problem is reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

This was a shared file that anyone can open. It appears that someone opened the Excel Online on an older version of Excel and in turn, it didn't support some of the changes that were made when saved to Excel Online, in turn messing a lot of my formulas up.